# Setting up a high performance computing cluster on servers that run different OSs

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, hpc

In my lab, we have several servers used for the simulation programs, but they worked independently. Now I want to combine them to become a cluster using MPICH to make them communicate. But there exists a problem, which is that these servers have different OSs. Some of them are Redhat, and some of them are Ubuntu. And on the homepage of MPICH, I saw that download sites of these two different operating systems are different, so will it be possible to set up a cluster with different operating system? And how to do it?

The reason why I don't want to reinstall these servers is that there are too many data on them and they are under used when I ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not feasible to get this working properly. You should be able to get the same version of an MPI implementation manually installed on different distributions. They might even talk to each other properly. But as soon you try to run actual applications, with dynamic libraries, you will get into trouble with different versions of shared libraries, glibc etc. You will be tempted to link everything statically or build different binaries for the different distributions. At the end of the day, you will just chase one issue you run into after another.

As a side node, combining some servers together with MPI does not make a High Performance Computing cluster. For instance an HPC system has sophisticated high performance interconnects and a high performance parallel file system.

Also note that your typical HPC application is going to run poorly on heterogeneous hardware (as in each node has different CPU / memory configurations).

Comment: what if my program can be divided by into different loops, and each loop can execute separately? I only need to pass the initial value to the different slave nodes, and then each node don't need other communication. The final result can be write to each slave node. Can this frame work?

Comment: The issue is not the decomposition of work, but the infrastructure - which will make an attempt to do so incredibly painful. There are other distributed computing frameworks more suitable for heterogeneous soft- and hardware environments.

Comment: do you have any idea about this heterogeneous environment?

Comment: I was thinking about things like hadoop, docker, ... but I know too little the problems you are trying to solve and those technologies to give a good recommendation.